# 2D grid data structure for nearest free cell

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Consider a 2000 x 2000 2D bool array.  100,000 elements are set to true, the rest to false.

Given a cell (x1,y1) we need to find the nearest cell (x2,y2) (by manhattan distance: abs(x1-x2) + abs(y1-y2)) that is false.

One way to do that would be to:

```
for (int dist = 0; true; dist++)
    for ((x2,y2) in all cells dist away from (x1,y1))
        if (!array[x2,y2])
            return (x2,y2);
```

In the worst case we would have to iterate through 100,000 cells before finding the free one.

Is there a data structure we could use rather than a 2D array that would allow us to perform this search quicker?

Comment: Will the array be updated? Will you do only many searches?

Comment: Is the array constant and you are given many queries on it? Or is it one query per array question? There is really no point in creating clever data structure if you are going to use it only once.

Comment: Sorry, yes, the data will change - once a cell is found it is marked true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the data is constant and you have many queries on it:

You might want to use a [k-d tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree), and look for the nearest neighbor. Insert `(i,j)` for each element such that `arr[i][j] = false`. The standard k-d tree uses euclidean distance but I *think* one can modify it to use manhattan distances instead..

If the data is used for one query: 

You will need at least `Omega(n*m)` ops to read the data and insert it into any data structure - so no point in doing that - the suggested solution will outperform only the build up of any data structure.

Comment: Typical kd-tree algorithms work with any [metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_%28mathematics%29) due to the [triangle inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality).

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested into look into [Region QuadTree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree). Here initially the entire image is modeled as the root since the image contains all 0s (assumption). Then when a particular pixel is set, the image is divided into 4 quadrants first and the 3 quadrants where the pixel is not included are left as leaves. The remaining quadrant is subdivided again and so on. This is reached till we have 4 point leaves out of which one is set. 
This representation will help to rule-out entire regions during the search and the search time can be optimized to O(log n)